# Quickly Reacquirable Locks

Tags: c

This is an algorithm that does not use OS synchronization primitives until two or more threads really access the critical section. Even in recursive "locks" of same thread, there is no real lock until a second thread is involved.

http://home.comcast.net/~pjbishop/Dave/QRL-OpLocks-BiasedLocking.pdf

There are two functions:

```
int qrlgeneric_acquire(qrlgeneric_lock *L, int id);  
void qrlgeneric_release(qrlgeneric_lock *L, int acquiredquickly);
```

**qrlgeneric_acquire:** called when the thread wants to lock. `id` is thread id
**qrlgeneric_release**: called when the thread wants to unlock

**Example:**
**Thread_1** which already locked calls `qrlgeneric_acquire` again, so a recursive lock will be performed. At the same time, **Thread_2** calls `qrlgeneric_acquire`, so there will be contention (two threads wants to lock, real os sync primitive will be used).

**Thread_1** will reach this condition on line `4`.

```
04 if (BIASED(id) == status) // SO: this means this thread already has this lock
05 {    
06   L->lockword.h.quicklock = 1;
07   if (BIASED(id) == HIGHWORD(L->lockword.data))
08     return 1;
09   L->lockword.h.quicklock = 0; /* I didn’t get the lock, so be sure */
10   /* not to block the process that did */
11 }
```

**Thread_2** will reach this condition on line `35`. `CAS` is **compare_and_swap** atomic operation.

```
34 unsigned short biaslock = L->lockword.h.quicklock;
35 if (CAS(&L->lockword,
36   MAKEDWORD(biaslock, status),
37   MAKEDWORD(biaslock, REVOKED)))
38 {
39   /* I’m the revoker. Set up the default lock. */
40   /* *** INITIALIZE AND ACQUIRE THE DEFAULT LOCK HERE *** */
41   /* Note: this is an uncontended acquire, so it */
42   /* can be done without use of atomics if this is */
43   /* desirable. */
44   L->lockword.h.status = DEFAULT;
45
46   /* Wait until quicklock is free */
47   while (LOWWORD(L->lockword.data))
48   ;
49   return 0; /* And then it’s mine */
50 }
```

From the comments on line `9` and `47`, you can see that the statement at line `9` is there for support the statement on line `47` so the **Thread_2** doesn't spin lock there forever.

**QUESTION:** It seems from those comments on line `9` and `47` that those two conditions above should never both succeed, otherwise the **Thread_2** will spin lock on the line `47` because the statement on line `9` will not be executed. **THE PROBLEM** is I need to help to understand how it is possible that it will never happen that both them succeed, because I still think it can happen:

**1. Thread_1:** `06   L->lockword.h.quicklock = 1;`
**2. Thread_2:** `34 unsigned short biaslock = L->lockword.h.quicklock;`
**3. Thread_1:** `if (BIASED(id) == HIGHWORD(L->lockword.data))`
**4. Thread_2:** `35 if (CAS(&L->lockword,MAKEDWORD(biaslock, status),MAKEDWORD(biaslock, REVOKED)))`

**3.** This condition will succeed because **Thread_2** didn't change anything yet.
**4.** This condition will succeed, because the points **1** and **3** didn't affect it.

The result is I think they can both succeed, but this means that **Thread_2** will spin lock on the line `47` until the **Thread_1** releases the lock. I think this is definitely wrong and shouldn't happen, so I probably don't understand it. Can anyone help?

**Whole algorithm:**

```
/* statuses for qrl locks */
#define BIASED(id) ((int)(id) << 2)
#define NEUTRAL 1
#define DEFAULT 2
#define REVOKED 3
#define ISBIASED(status) (0 == ((status) & 3))
/* word manipulation (big-endian versions shown here) */
#define MAKEDWORD(low, high) (((unsigned int)(low) << 16) | (high))
#define HIGHWORD(dword) ((unsigned short)dword)
#define LOWWORD(dword) ((unsigned short)(((unsigned int)(dword)) >> 16))

typedef volatile struct tag_qrlgeneric_lock
{
  volatile union
  {
    volatile struct
    {
      volatile short quicklock;
      volatile short status;
    }
    h;
    volatile int data;
  }
 lockword;
/* *** PLUS WHATEVER FIELDS ARE NEEDED FOR THE DEFAULT LOCK *** */
}
qrlgeneric_lock;

int qrlgeneric_acquire(qrlgeneric_lock *L, int id)
{
   int status = L->lockword.h.status;

   /* If the lock’s mine, I can reenter by just setting a flag */
   if (BIASED(id) == status)
   {
     L->lockword.h.quicklock = 1;
     if (BIASED(id) == HIGHWORD(L->lockword.data))
       return 1;
     L->lockword.h.quicklock = 0; /* I didn’t get the lock, so be sure */
   /* not to block the process that did */
   }

   if (DEFAULT != status)
   {
   /* If the lock is unowned, try to claim it */
     if (NEUTRAL == status)
     {
       if (CAS(&L->lockword, /* By definition, if we saw */
           MAKEDWORD(0, NEUTRAL), /* neutral, the lock is unheld */
           MAKEDWORD(1, BIASED(id))))
       {
          return 1;
       }
       /* If I didn’t bias the lock to me, someone else just grabbed
       it. Fall through to the revocation code */
       status = L->lockword.h.status; /* resample */
     }

     /* If someone else owns the lock, revoke them */
     if (ISBIASED(status))
     {
       do
       {
         unsigned short biaslock = L->lockword.h.quicklock;
         if (CAS(&L->lockword,
             MAKEDWORD(biaslock, status),
             MAKEDWORD(biaslock, REVOKED)))
         {
          /* I’m the revoker. Set up the default lock. */
          /* *** INITIALIZE AND ACQUIRE THE DEFAULT LOCK HERE *** */
          /* Note: this is an uncontended acquire, so it */
          /* can be done without use of atomics if this is */
          /* desirable. */
           L->lockword.h.status = DEFAULT;

           /* Wait until quicklock is free */
           while (LOWWORD(L->lockword.data))
           ;
           return 0; /* And then it’s mine */
          }

          /* The CAS could have failed and we got here for either of
          two reasons. First, another process could have done the
          revoking; in this case we need to fall through to the
          default path once the other process is finished revoking.
          Secondly, the bias process could have acquired or released
          the biaslock field; in this case we need merely retry. */
          status = L->lockword.h.status;
       }
       while (ISBIASED(L->lockword.h.status));
     }

     /* If I get here, the lock has been revoked by someone other
     than me. Wait until they’re done revoking, then fall through
     to the default code. */
     while (DEFAULT != L->lockword.h.status)
     ;
   }

     /* Regular default lock from here on */
     assert(DEFAULT == L->lockword.h.status);
     /* *** DO NORMAL (CONTENDED) DEFAULT LOCK ACQUIRE FUNCTION HERE *** */
     return 0;
  }

  void qrlgeneric_release(qrlgeneric_lock *L, int acquiredquickly)
  {
     if (acquiredquickly)
     L->lockword.h.quicklock = 0;
     else
     {
     /* *** DO NORMAL DEFAULT LOCK RELEASE FUNCTION HERE *** */
     }
  }
```

Comment: How old is that PDF?

Comment: @user3386109: I don't know, but there is reference from year 2001, so it is max 14 year old

Comment: Yup, that sounds about right. I stopped using lockless multithreading about 10 years ago due to complications (um, advances) in processor design. [This article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee418650(v=vs.85).aspx) may be of interest.

Comment: @EOF: quicklock isn't part of status.

Comment: these two lines: ' while (LOWWORD(L->lockword.data))
;'  will burn CPU cycles rather than allowing a context swap.  so any other thread will NOT be executed until/unless the OS is organized to use  preemptive timeslicing.  *I* would strongly suggest NOT using any of the suggested code.   a mutex, with mutex_init(), mutex_lock() and mutex_unlock() will cause a context swap when another thread has the mutex 'locked'

Comment: @user3629249: yes that is exactly what i think it does, but what it shoudn't, so i am not sure if i understand it badly or it really spin lock there

Comment: Each of the sequence points (basically the semicolons) practically *guarantee* that race conditions will happen within this very code. Even betwixt the sequence points there are points where races could happen; for example, though `*L` and `(*L).lockwood` (equivalent to `L->lockwood`) are `volatile`, `L` is not so the expression that is `*L` may be subject to optimisation such as reusing the result (since it's repeated over and over) or reorganisation... In summary, this is **very bad code**! Just use `pthread_mutex_lock`, or when you don't want blocking locks, `pthread_mutex_trylock`.